# ReBus Application shows Message Queue Performance Issue in ANTS Profiler

Tags: message-queue, msmq, rebus, ants, msmq-transaction

We have web Application built in AngularJS, **ReBus** and NHibernate. While working on Performance optimization, **REDGATE's ANTS Profiler** shows that most of the time required to execute **MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage**

[image: ANTS ScreenShot to display execution flow]

And Call Graph will look like this,

[image]

So does Message queue taking more time, Why this behavior is observed, what will be the possible options to make this time less or so.
Note: I have not added code because for all scenarios, only this part taking 90% time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that what you are observing is the fact that the worker thread is BLOCKED for a small duration, while it is waiting for the next message to become available.

If the queue always has messages in it, I suspect the time spent in `StaleSafeReceiveMessage` will be greatly diminished.

In other words, I don't think it is a problem at all :)